# Difference between get and resource with except

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple app, with one controller, with only two actions.

There's a significant difference between these two forms of routing?

`get 'products/show'
 get 'products/index'`

or

`resources :products, :only: [:show, :index]`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html

There is no difference - it will act in the same way. Choose the one with more comfortable syntax for you.

Answer (score 1):

With *resources* you can simply declare the common routes in a single line of code.

Additionally, *resources* automatically uses specific HTTP method for each route and adds the common param to the url, e.g. *id for the *show* route.

There is one difference with the helpers too. For you example these will be:

```
get 'products/show' -> products_show_path
get 'products/index' -> products_index_path
```

or

```
product_path for show 
products_path for index
```